# Why doesn't my Thrustmaster Dual Trigger 3-in-1 Rumble Force vibrate when it's supposed to?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, controllers

I've bought the Thrustmaster Dual Trigger 3-in-1 Rumble Force controller, it claims to support force feedback on PC, but nothing seems to actually cause it to rumble and is no 'Test forces' tab in the gamepad's driver settings. I'm running the latest official driver, 2009_FFD_2 (2009 Force Feedback Driver, revision 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force feedback support for this controller seems to be broken in the latest driver (2009_FFD_2), you should get the previous revision, 2009_FFD_1, [available from the Thrustmaster support website](http://ts.thrustmaster.com/download/accessories/pc/Unified_Drivers/2009_FFD_1.exe). Uninstall the current driver via the control panel, reboot and install 2009_FFD_1, the gamepad's rumble feature should now function properly.